# SPI Interrupt Bit-Offset / Too Early

Tags: gpio, spi, raspi-config, pi-pico, interrupts

I´m running an SPI Slave on my Pico and executing an interrupt when 16 bits of Data are received.
I visualized the interrupt with a gpio spike on the beginning and end of the interrupt to see when it´s getting triggerd and how long the interrupt takes to execute.
The interrupt has an offset tho. Sometimes its getting triggerd right after the 16th bit of data arrived, and sometimes the interrupt is coming at a random bit like in this case the 12th bit:

[image: Interrupt.png]

Z1 (yellow) = Gpio trigger (interrupt)
Z2 (red) = Clock
Z3 (blue) = Data
Z4 = dont mind

```
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/spi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hardware/irq.h"
#include "hardware/structs/spi.h"
#include "hardware/resets.h"

#define BUF_LEN 1


uint16_t spi1out_buf[BUF_LEN];

void my_spi_handler() { 
  
  gpio_put(1, 1); //Begin Interrupt
  spi_read16_blocking(spi1, 0, spi1out_buf, BUF_LEN); 
  printf("%04x",spi1out_buf);                           
  gpio_put(1, 0); //End Interrupt
}

int main(){

    
    stdio_set_translate_crlf(&stdio_usb, false); 
    stdio_init_all();

    //Pin 8, 9, 10 as SPI 
    gpio_set_function(8, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);
    gpio_set_function(9, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);
    gpio_set_function(10, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);

    //Pin 1 GPIO Output 
    gpio_init(1);
    gpio_set_dir(1, GPIO_OUT);
    
    //SPI setting
   
    spi_init(spi1, 1000 * 1000);
    spi_set_format(spi1,16,SPI_CPOL_1,SPI_CPHA_1,SPI_MSB_FIRST);  
    spi_set_slave(spi1, 1);
    irq_set_exclusive_handler(SPI1_IRQ, my_spi_handler);
    irq_set_enabled(SPI1_IRQ, true);
    irq_set_priority(SPI1_IRQ,0);
    spi1_hw->imsc = 1 << 2;

    
    my_spi_handler();
  

while(1){}

}
```

Any ideas why the interrupt is coming early? Do i need to clear a certain register before starting?
I made sure that the interrupt is actually the interrupt from the current data word and not from the word that came before - so no delay.
For some reason the rx fifo is filled after only 12bits.

Comment: `why the interrupt is coming early?` ... maybe it is actually late

Comment: Putting a printf call in an interrupt handler is generally a bad idea; it can sometimes introduce a sizeable delay, which might be the cause of your problem. Simplify the interrupt handler by just saving its data in an array, then use the main loop (or another thread) to print the contents of that array.